# The service is currently unavailable | Firebase cloud_firestore issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, android-emulator

When I try Firebase Firestore on my Android device, the error below is occurred.

> [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable.
> This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by
> retrying with a backoff.

This doesn't happen when I try with emulator even same code.

### What I doing

Updated version of firebase packages.

```
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.1.4
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.0
```

Using `FutureBuilder` to get fields.

In my `StatefulWidget`;

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myInterstitial.load();
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
            .get(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
            FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            return const Text("Document does not exist ");
          }

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           .............
```

I don't know why but `snapshot.hasError` is alaways `true`, and `snapshot.error.toString()` returns error above.

I didn't change any code but it works on emulator. However the build (build with `$ flutter build appbundle --no-sound-null-safety`, `$ flutter build apk --no-sound-null-safety` and '$ flutter run --no-sound-null-safety') doesn't work better.

The biggest mystery is that everything works correctly in the emulator.

How can I solve this?

### flutter doctor -v

```
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 400608f101 (8 weeks ago), 2021-09-15 15:50:26 -0700
    • Engine revision 1d521d89d8
    • Dart version 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.2.beta)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at D:\Android
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at D:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\yukik\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.28.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • Pixel 5a (mobile)                  • 16121JECB02429 • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • Android SDK built for x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554  • android-x86    • Android 10 (API 29) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                       • chrome         • web-javascript • Google Chrome 95.0.4638.69
    • Edge (web)                         • edge           • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 95.0.1020.44

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Use an Android image with Google services; and I've also down-voted, because "What I doing" doesn't feature a single line of code, which makes the issue irreproducible (despite an educated guess may already answer it).

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this recently in a React Native project with Android emulator.

The only thing that solved was to delete the emulator device and creating another.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30595055)

Comment: But this is worth to do

Answer (score 0):

I was experience a similar issue ,
firebase/firestore (while performing get , set and other operations) on emulator , everything was working fine on an actual android device but not on android emulator,
what I did to fix was , changed my android studio to 2021 patch version It fixed the error and everything started working .
Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).